# Comparing two strings to get uniqueness percent

Tags: php, algorithm, compare

I'm looking for a sulotion.
I have two strings that I need to compare one to each other and get the uniqueness percent.

For example:

```
{
String A = "Hello"
String B = "Hello"
Uniqueness percent = 0%
}

{
String A = "Hello friend"
String B = "Hello mate"
Uniqueness percent = 50%
}

{
String A = "Hey"
String B = "Hello"
Uniqueness percent = 100%
}
```

Comment: What about words that are present in both strings but at another location?  And what about words that occur more than once in one of the strings?

Comment: What are the criteria for uniqueness? What if its "Hello friend" vs "Well hello, sir?" Do you split by words? What about punctuation?

Comment: As the others hinted, it's always important to understand and validate the requirements, and then to design an algorithm, before you begin to write code.  Getting into that habit will save you an unimaginable amount of time during your career.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few linguistic functions in PHP which you can use.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php

As your question is missing details about the criteria for the uniqueness you have to check if one of these fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this code is based on similar_text() php function, as I can see it compares strings by letters not whole words, look at example:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST["str_a"]) && isset($_REQUEST["str_b"])) {

        $str_a = $_REQUEST["str_a"];    
        $str_b = $_REQUEST["str_b"];    

        function compare_them($str_1, $str_2) {

            $str_1 = trim(strtolower($str_1));
            $str_2 = trim(strtolower($str_2));

            similar_text($str_1, $str_2, $percentage);

            $formated_percents = number_format($percentage);

            return $formated_percents; 

        }

        $calculated = compare_them($str_a, $str_b);

    }


?>

<form action="" method="get">

    string a: <input type="text" value="" name="str_a" />
    <br />
    string b: <input type="text" value="" name="str_b" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<h2>
<?php 

    if(isset($_REQUEST["str_a"]) && isset($_REQUEST["str_b"])) { 

        print "string a = " . $str_a . " <br />string b = " . $str_b . " <br />percents match = " . $calculated . "%"; 

    }

?>
</h2>
```

**Here is live example:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/percent/percent.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar_text()

```
similar_text($string1,$string2,$percentage);
echo $percentage;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

If you are looking for performance critical solution then you need to use optimized algorithm (In most cases this is a good solution).